# Transport username sent instead of sender's email | Symfony Mailer

Tags: symfony, mailer, symfony6

I'am experiencing the issue of receiving the transport username (email) as the sender instead of the email written in the ****`from()`**** function when sending emails using Symfony Mailer.

Here is the code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Bridge\Google\Transport\GmailSmtpTransport;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;

$transport = new GmailSmtpTransport($username, $password);
$mailer = new Mailer($transport);

$email = (new Email())
    ->from(new Address($data["email"]))
    ->to("dest@gmail.com")
    ->subject(sprintf("Apply for a %s.", ucfirst($data["subject"])))
    ->html($template);

$mailer->send($email);
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: "but the transport email is sent as a "from" email" - what does that mean? Also, please share all code **in text form**

Comment: @NicoHaase, When you receive an email, it shows from someone [from receiver@gmail.com], but in my case, I receive [from test@gmail.com which is the transport username]

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Does the transport you use allow setting a different sender address?

Comment: @Medinho please do not share code as image and use "code block" inside editor. It's important in case someone try to test it